# Problems with Jquery .on()

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamically-generated

I'm attempting to use `.on()` to add a text field when a dynamically created button is clicked.  However, for whatever reason, I can't seem to get it working.  Anyone see what's wrong?  Thanks for any help and sorry if it's something obvious (I'm afraid that it might be but I just can't see it).

```js
$('#the-basics input.typeahead').keyup(function() {
  var prs = $(this).val().split(' ');
  if (!$("#the-basics span.newEntityButtons").length) {
    var $newEntity = $('<span class="newEntityButtons">' + '</span>');
    $newEntity.appendTo($("#the-basics"));
    var $newPerson = $('<input type="button" value="New Person" id="addpersonbutton" class="newHolder newPerson" />');
    $newPerson.appendTo($("span.newEntityButtons"));
  }
});

$('div#example').on('click', '#addpersonbutton', function() {
  var epo = new Date().getTime();
  var theelement = '<span class="nested-fields person">' +
    '<input id="stockholder_people_attributes_' + epo + '_fname" name="stockholder[people_attributes][' + epo + '][fname]" value="' + prs[0] + '">' +
    '<a class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash remove_fields existing" href="#"></a>' +
    '</span>';
  $('div.new_person.new_fields').prepend(theelement);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="example">
  <div id="the-basics">
    <input class="typeahead">
  </div>
  <div class="new_person new_fields">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: remove hash from id `id="addpersonbutton"` instead of `id="#addpersonbutton"`

Comment: agree with @jcubic, also make sure that id must not be same for multiple elements. This will break your jquery code for handling events using ids. `id="#addpersonbutton"`  change this line so that id will be unique all the time.

Comment: @jcubic good catch; unfortunately there's apparently something else wrong :-P

Comment: getting an error `Uncaught ReferenceError: prs is not defined ` in the onCkilck function

Comment: those who voted -2 care to comment why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `#` from the `New Person` button's `id`.

```
var $newPerson = $('<input type="button" value="New Person" id="addpersonbutton" class="newHolder newPerson" />');
```

Declare `prs` outside the click event like following.

```
var prs;

$('#the-basics input.typeahead').keyup(function () {
    prs = $(this).val().split(' ');
    if (!$("#the-basics span.newEntityButtons").length) {
        var $newEntity = $('<span class="newEntityButtons">' + '</span>');
        $newEntity.appendTo($("#the-basics"));
        var $newPerson = $('<input type="button" value="New Person" id="addpersonbutton" class="newHolder newPerson" />');
        $newPerson.appendTo($("span.newEntityButtons"));
    }
});
```

Comment: Good catch, but apparently there's something else wrong :-P

Comment: It wont work Azim. You can try it. I was trying that

Comment: not a good idea to move it into global scope. he can just duplicate it as a local variable again in second function

Comment: Why would he do that? @llamerr

Comment: to not declare variable globally and trash global scope? I made an edit to my answer to show what I meant @Azim

Answer (score 2):

**Changes I made**

► Declared variable `prs` as a global variable

► Remove `#` from the New Person button's id.

**Working Demo**

```js
var prs = '';
$('#the-basics input.typeahead').keyup(function() {
  prs = $(this).val().split(' ');
  if (!$("#the-basics span.newEntityButtons").length) {
    var $newEntity = $('<span class="newEntityButtons">' + '</span>');
    $newEntity.appendTo($("#the-basics"));
    var $newPerson = $('<input type="button" value="New Person" id="addpersonbutton" class="newHolder newPerson" />');
    $newPerson.appendTo($("span.newEntityButtons"));
  }
});

$('div#example').on('click', '#addpersonbutton', function() {
  var epo = new Date().getTime();
  var theelement = '<span class="nested-fields person">' +
    '<input id="stockholder_people_attributes_' + epo + '_fname" name="stockholder[people_attributes][' + epo + '][fname]" value="' + prs[0] + '">' +
    '<a class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash remove_fields existing" href="#"></a>' +
    '</span>';
  $('div.new_person.new_fields').prepend(theelement);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="example">
  <div id="the-basics">
    <input class="typeahead">
  </div>
  <div class="new_person new_fields">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: not a good idea to move it into global scope. he can just duplicate it as a local variable again in second function

Comment: @llamerr It wont duplicate since it is not declared again.

Comment: I know it won't be duplicated since it's in global scope. that's why I wrote that it's better to duplicate declaration locally same way as he did it before (what I actually mean, sorry if it's unclear)

Comment: @llamerr Not worry; I actually have all this wrapped up in a function so it's not in the global scope.

Answer (score 1):

```
var prs = $(this).val().split(' ');
```

is not a global variable, and inaccessible inside `$('div#example').on('click', '#addpersonbutton', function() {` so duplicate it inside your second function

EDIT: to make it clear:

```
$('#the-basics input.typeahead').keyup(function() {
    var prs = $(this).val().split(' ');
    if (!$("#the-basics span.newEntityButtons").length) {
        var $newEntity = $('<span class="newEntityButtons">' + '</span>');
        $newEntity.appendTo($("#the-basics"));
        var $newPerson = $('<input type="button" value="New Person" id="addpersonbutton" class="newHolder newPerson" />');
        $newPerson.appendTo($("span.newEntityButtons"));
    }
});

$('div#example').on('click', '#addpersonbutton', function() {
    var prs = $(this).val().split(' ');
    var epo = new Date().getTime();
    var theelement = '<span class="nested-fields person">' +
        '<input id="stockholder_people_attributes_' + epo + '_fname" name="stockholder[people_attributes][' + epo + '][fname]" value="' + prs[0] + '">' +
        '<a class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash remove_fields existing" href="#"></a>' +
        '</span>';
    $('div.new_person.new_fields').prepend(theelement);
});
```